# Heroku, ror, no dynos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a ruby on rails app on Heroku, its been there for while with one dyno ( kinda experminetation project ).
Today I changed some text entries in one of the files under views. started the server locally and got it ti run, did a push to heroku and all of the sudden after that push Heroku stopped working. Running heroku logs I get this

```
  013-06-15T22:09:30.344294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

So I login to heroku to see whats the matter, I notice I don't have any dynos available for this app. After some googling I got some results to add a dyno using this command

```
  heroku ps:scale web=1

  Scaling web dynos... failed
  !    No such type as web.
```

But the message coming back was that no such type as web!!

What did I do wrong? All the edit I did was some text ( its my blog ).

PS : 
I don't have a procfile, and I checked on my git history and I never did have a Procfile, and this has worked before.

Comment: Do you have a `Procfile`? What’s in it?

Comment: no I don;t have a procfile, and I checked on my git history and I never did have a Procfile, and this has worked before!!

Answer (score 1):

ok so I found the answer,
Basically I had to add a Procfile ( still don't know why because my app was working before without one ), and in that procfile I do

```
 web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -E $RACK_ENV
```

Heroku recommends this approach for production apps.

link to heroku article

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3#deploy-your-application-to-heroku